# tick 2 values on a multi-selection list box via rules

Tags: infopath

I have a multi-selection list box with multiple values in, and when a user selects a value from a dropdown, I want this to trigger a rule that then selects two of the values in the multi-selection list box. I have tried setting the fields value one for each value I want selected but that only selects the last one I set the fields value for. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Is it JSOM you are trying? Could you please share the code as of now?

Comment: i want to ruse the rules in InfoPath not jsom